# Is the Euclidean distance monotonic under affine transformation?

Tags: normed-spaces, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Let us say we have an Affine transformation: $\vec{\gamma}=\eta \vec{\tau} +\vec{\kappa}$, where $\eta$ is a diagonal matrix. Specifically, $\vec{\tau}{=}[\tau_x \  \tau_y\  \tau_z]^T$ forms a sphere, i.e. $\tau_x^2 + \tau_y^2 + \tau_z^2 = 1$. The resulting affine transformation distorts the sphere into an ellipsoid: $\frac{(\gamma_x-\kappa_x)}{\eta_x}^2 + \frac{(\gamma_y-\kappa_y)}{\eta_y}^2 + \frac{(\gamma_z-\kappa_z)}{\eta_z}^2 = 1$. The matrix $\eta$ and the vector $\vec{\kappa}$ are such that the resulting ellipsoid lies within the initial sphere. Under these conditions, if the two points on the ellipsoid, $\vec{\gamma_1}$ and $\vec{\gamma_2}$, have the highest Euclidean distance, then can we say that the corresponding points $\vec{\tau_1}$ and $\vec{\tau_2}$ on the sphere have the highest distance, i.e., do they lie on the opposite ends on the sphere?

Comment: No, certainly not.  Intuitively, if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are at opposite ends of the axis that is most “squashed” by the transformation, then the distance between them can easily shrink enough under the transformation to violate monotonicity.

Comment: Thanks, the question needs rephrasing. I wanted to know if the Euclidean distance between two points $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ on the resulting ellipsoid is the highest, then are $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ at opposite ends of the sphere?

Comment: Oh, that's a very different question.  Then yes.  If the $\eta_i$ are all different, then there will be a unique pair of farthest-apart points on the ellipsoid, corresponding to the endpoints of an axis-aligned diameter on the original sphere.  If the largest $\eta_i$ is degenerate, there will be a whole family of such pairs; but each will correspond to the endpoints of some diameter on the original sphere.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a formal proof of this?